# Existence of non-extremal point of a function on a line segment

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, optimization

I am stuck in the following question:

Let $x,y\in \mathbb{R}^n$ such that $x\ne y$ and $f:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$.  We write $]x,y[{}=\{tx+(1-t)y:0<t<1\}$. I would like to know whether there exists $z\in{}]x,y[$ such that for every neighborhood $Z$ of $z$ there exists $\bar z\in Z\cap{}]x,y[$ such that $\bar z\ne z$ and 
$$
f(\bar z)\leq f(z).
$$

Thank you for all kind help.

Comment: What is $]x,y[$?  Is $f$ continuous?

Comment: $]x,y[=\{tx+(1-t)y:0<t<1\}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are only countably many points $z\in{}]x,y[$ such that this *doesn't* hold.  Indeed, for any particular $Z$, there is at most one $z\in Z$ such that the condition fails for $z$ on $Z$, namely the point of $Z\cap{}]x,y[$ where $f$ takes its unique minimum value (if such a point exists).  Now let $\{Z_n\}$ be a countable basis for the topology on $]x,y[$.  If the condition fails for some $z\in{} ]x,y[$ and some neighborhood $Z$ of $z$, then there is an $n$ such that $z\in Z_n\subseteq Z$, and so $z$ must be the point of $Z_n$ where $f$ takes its unique minimum value.  There is at most one such point for each $n$, so there are at most countably many such $z$.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Could you make clear your answer?

Comment: I have added a bit more detail.

Comment: Thanks. If we replace $\mathbb{R}^n$ by a Banach space whether we have the same conclusion?

Comment: Yes; all this argument uses is that $]x,y[$ is second-countable, which is always true.

Comment: I am not clear why there is only one point $z$ in $Z_n$ such that the condition fails. Could you make clear this argument?

Comment: If you have two such points $z$ and $z'$, then $f(z)<f(z')$ and $f(z')<f(z)$, which is impossible.

Comment: Dear Eric Wofsey, Please give your comments on my question at: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1560808/quasiconvex-and-lower-semicontinuous-function